# What is the name for the books with side-by-side bilingual text?

Tags: terminology, translation

I'm trying to learn a new language, and looking for works with interleaved Norwegian-English texts. It can be either alternating sentences, paragraphs, or pages, so that I can juxtapose the corresponding vocabulary, structure, et cetera in the two languages without much difficulty. The genre is not of much importance for now.

**Is there a particular name for this formatting I can use as a keyword for my searches?** I am asking for the naming for this book format, rather than resources themselves. I came across a term "parallel text".

Comment: Which I notice that you used in the heading of your question. Searching for bilingual or parallel Beowulf gives you very similar results in a search-engine.

Comment: Penguin has a series called "parallel text": https://www.penguinrandomhouse.com/series/BMH/penguin-parallel-text

Comment: @MoziburUllah yeah, but apparently the word I used in the header was the only word I did not search in Google :) When I did that, I found out that "parallel text" and "parallel corpus" are the terms for a bilingual work and a collection of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have already found out, if texts are presented side by side, these are known as [**parallel text**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_text); in the case of translations, the usual term is **bilingual parallel text**.

Bilingual parallel texts can be used as a language learning resource; see for example the article [6 Spots to Pick Up Texts in the Bilingual Parallel Universe](https://www.fluentu.com/blog/bilingual-parallel-texts/) on FluentU. There are entire corpora of parallel texts; see for example [OPUS - an open source parallel corpus](http://opus.nlpl.eu/). For other examples, see for example this [parallel translation of Beowulf](http://www.heorot.dk/beo-intro-rede.html) and this [parallel German translation of the Kalevala](https://www.hs-augsburg.de/~harsch/germanica/Chronologie/19Jh/Schiefner/sch_ka01.html).

If the translation is not presented on the facing page but on lines that alternate with the original text, this is called **interlinear translation**. For example, there are interlinear translations of [Chaucer's Canterbury Tales](http://sites.fas.harvard.edu/~chaucer/teachslf/tr-index.htm), of the [Bible](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/)

Comment: Another example is this lovely [triple parallel text version](https://people.umass.edu/klement/tlp/tlp.html) of Wittgenstein's Tractatus, with the original German, and two translations.